# Topshelf enabled windows service won't debug

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, topshelf

Using Visual Studio 2015. Created a windows service project. I'm trying to use topshelf, but can't seem to debug.

Output debug / window says:

Topshelf v3.3.154.0, .NET Framework v4.0.30319.42000
Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost Error: 0 : An exception occurred, System.IO.IOException: The operation completed successfully.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.Console.set_Title(String value)
   at Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost.Run()

For those not familiar with Topshelf: http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Appears Topshelf expects the output type be set to "Console Application."

Project Properties/Application/Output Type: Console Application.

I guess I missed the key concept which is to create a console application which enables you to install it as a windows service.

Comment: This really helped me in a bind. Thanks for posting your solution!

Comment: Super easy fix.  thanks for taking the time to answer this question.    